# Are prepositions "of" and "from" interchangeable in this context?

Tags: prepositions

I wonder if it is exactly the same to say "the pupils OF that school" and "the pupils FROM that school".Does precising the name of the school, Woodlane School for example, would make either preposition more likely?

Comment: Whether or not you use the school's name makes no difference, but I think only someone with no connection to the school would use _from_.

Comment: I would use neither: that school's pupils

Comment: @Lambie "A group of schoolchildren were creating a disturbance in the street; I think they were all from Woodlane School."

Answer (score 2):

Saying "The pupils of Woodlane School" sounds like you're describing that school and how the pupils generally behave. For example "The pupils of Woodlane School had a habit of drinking chocolate milk with their lunches."

Saying "The pupils from Woodlane School" implies that the pupils are not physically at the school, and sets up some sort of contrast with other pupils. For example "The pupils from Woodlane School brought chocolate milk for their lunches, while the pupils from Springville Elementary only had regular."